# Best paint remover for hardwood floors?

Tags: paint, hardwood

Whats the best way to remove paint off of hardwood floors?

We were painting my daughters room and didn't notice she accidentally got paint on her shoe till after it was too late.

We've tried paint thinner, goo gone, and scraping it with a razor, but we don't want to stain or ruin the floor. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you are going to have to resign yourself to stripping and refinishing that area of the floor.

Comment: Covering floor with old bedsheets or brown paper etc - there are even products designed for this will be a good idea for next time...

Answer (score 0):

If it's latex paint and the accident happened within the last couple of days, use an ammonia-based cleaner such as original Windex. It shouldn't harm the finish (but test in an inconspicuous spot first) and it should dissolve and clean the latex paint.

If it's oil-based paint, you may have to strip and refinish the floor.